# Object doesn't support property or method Error on internet explorer IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using this jquery circleChart.min.js plugin for circle chart .It's working fine on all browsers but the following error occur on internet explorer 11 IE11.
How can I fix it??
[image]

```js
$(".circleChart#0").circleChart({
  size:150,
  value: 50,
  text: 0,
  onDraw: function(el, circle) {
    circle.text(Math.round(circle.value) + "%");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-circlechart@2.3.0/src/circleChart.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="circleChart" id="0"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try explicitly using `jQuery(".circleChart#0").circleChart(` and see if that solves anything

Comment: No @FrankerZ Same Error Message are coming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the script being served uses ES6 syntax and methods:

```
// ...
const defaults = {
// ...
Math.linearTween = (t, b, c, d) => c * t / d + b;
// ...
let copy = Object.assign({}, this);
```

A workaround would be to transpile the script to ES5 syntax with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) first (just paste in the code from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-circlechart@2.3.0/src/circleChart.min.js ), and to then install the required polyfills.

The big `<script>` text below is simply the Babeled and minified version of `circleChart.min.js`. Run the following snippet on IE11, and it works as expected:

```js
$(".circleChart#0").circleChart({
  size:150,
  value: 50,
  text: 0,
  onDraw: function(el, circle) {
    circle.text(Math.round(circle.value) + "%");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>"use strict";(function($){"use strict";$.fn.circleChart=function(options){var defaults={color:"#3459eb",backgroundColor:"#e6e6e6",background:!0,speed:2000,widthRatio:0.2,value:66,unit:'percent',counterclockwise:!1,size:110,startAngle:0,animate:!0,backgroundFix:!0,lineCap:"round",animation:"easeInOutCubic",text:!1,redraw:!1,cAngle:0,textCenter:!0,textSize:!1,textWeight:'normal',textFamily:'sans-serif',relativeTextSize:1/7,autoCss:!0,onDraw:!1};Math.linearTween=function(t,b,c,d){return c*t/d+b};Math.easeInQuad=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d;return c*t*t+b};Math.easeOutQuad=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d;return-c*t*(t-2)+b};Math.easeInOutQuad=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d/2;if(t<1)return c/2*t*t+b;t--;return-c/2*(t*(t-2)-1)+b};Math.easeInCubic=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d;return c*t*t*t+b};Math.easeOutCubic=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d;t--;return c*(t*t*t+1)+b};Math.easeInOutCubic=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d/2;if(t<1)return c/2*t*t*t+b;t-=2;return c/2*(t*t*t+2)+b};Math.easeInQuart=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d;return c*t*t*t*t+b};Math.easeOutQuart=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d;t--;return-c*(t*t*t*t-1)+b};Math.easeInOutQuart=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d/2;if(t<1)return c/2*t*t*t*t+b;t-=2;return-c/2*(t*t*t*t-2)+b};Math.easeInQuint=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d;return c*t*t*t*t*t+b};Math.easeOutQuint=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d;t--;return c*(t*t*t*t*t+1)+b};Math.easeInOutQuint=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d/2;if(t<1)return c/2*t*t*t*t*t+b;t-=2;return c/2*(t*t*t*t*t+2)+b};Math.easeInSine=function(t,b,c,d){return-c*Math.cos(t/d*(Math.PI/2))+c+b};Math.easeOutSine=function(t,b,c,d){return c*Math.sin(t/d*(Math.PI/2))+b};Math.easeInOutSine=function(t,b,c,d){return-c/2*(Math.cos(Math.PI*t/d)-1)+b};Math.easeInExpo=function(t,b,c,d){return c*Math.pow(2,10*(t/d-1))+b};Math.easeOutExpo=function(t,b,c,d){return c*(-Math.pow(2,-10*t/d)+1)+b};Math.easeInOutExpo=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d/2;if(t<1)return c/2*Math.pow(2,10*(t-1))+b;t--;return c/2*(-Math.pow(2,-10*t)+2)+b};Math.easeInCirc=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d;return-c*(Math.sqrt(1-t*t)-1)+b};Math.easeOutCubic=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d;t--;return c*(t*t*t+1)+b};Math.easeInOutCubic=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d/2;if(t<1)return c/2*t*t*t+b;t-=2;return c/2*(t*t*t+2)+b};Math.easeOutCirc=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d;t--;return c*Math.sqrt(1-t*t)+b};Math.easeInOutCirc=function(t,b,c,d){t/=d/2;if(t<1)return-c/2*(Math.sqrt(1-t*t)-1)+b;t-=2;return c/2*(Math.sqrt(1-t*t)+1)+b};var Circle=function Circle(pos,bAngle,eAngle,cAngle,radius,lineWidth,sAngle,settings){var circle=Object.create(Circle.prototype);circle.pos=pos;circle.bAngle=bAngle;circle.eAngle=eAngle;circle.cAngle=cAngle;circle.radius=radius;circle.lineWidth=lineWidth;circle.sAngle=sAngle;circle.settings=settings;return circle};Circle.prototype={onDraw:function onDraw(el){if(this.settings.onDraw!==!1){var copy=Object.assign({},this);var units={'percent':rToP,'rad':function rad(e){return e},'default':rToD};copy.value=(units[this.settings.unit]||units['default'])(copy.cAngle);copy.text=function(text){return setCircleText(el,text)};copy.settings.onDraw(el,copy)}},drawBackground:function drawBackground(ctx){ctx.beginPath();ctx.arc(this.pos,this.pos,this.settings.backgroundFix?this.radius*0.9999:this.radius,0,2*Math.PI);ctx.lineWidth=this.settings.backgroundFix?this.lineWidth*0.95:this.lineWidth;ctx.strokeStyle=this.settings.backgroundColor;ctx.stroke()},draw:function draw(ctx){ctx.beginPath();if(this.settings.counterclockwise){var k=2*Math.PI;ctx.arc(this.pos,this.pos,this.radius,k-this.bAngle,k-(this.bAngle+this.cAngle),this.settings.counterclockwise)}else{ctx.arc(this.pos,this.pos,this.radius,this.bAngle,this.bAngle+this.cAngle,this.settings.counterclockwise)}
ctx.lineWidth=this.lineWidth;ctx.lineCap=this.settings.lineCap;ctx.strokeStyle=this.settings.color;ctx.stroke()},animate:function animate(el,ctx,time,startTime,move){var _this=this;var mspf=new Date().getTime()-time;if(mspf<1){mspf=1}
if(time-startTime<this.settings.speed*1.05&&(!move&&this.cAngle*1000<=Math.floor(this.eAngle*1000)||move&&this.cAngle*1000>=Math.floor(this.eAngle*1000))){this.cAngle=Math[this.settings.animation]((time-startTime)/mspf,this.sAngle,this.eAngle-this.sAngle,this.settings.speed/mspf);ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.settings.size,this.settings.size);if(this.settings.background){this.drawBackground(ctx)}
this.draw(ctx);this.onDraw(el);time=new Date().getTime();rAF(function(){return _this.animate(el,ctx,time,startTime,move)})}else{this.cAngle=this.eAngle;ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.settings.size,this.settings.size);if(this.settings.background){this.drawBackground(ctx)}
this.draw(ctx);this.setCurrentAnglesData(el)}},setCurrentAnglesData:function setCurrentAnglesData(el){var units={'percent':rToP,'rad':function rad(e){return e},'default':rToD};var f=units[this.settings.unit]||units['default'];el.data("current-c-angle",f(this.cAngle));el.data("current-start-angle",f(this.bAngle))}};var setCircleText=function setCircleText(el,text){el.data("text",text);$(".circleChart_text",el).html(text)};var scaleCanvas=function scaleCanvas(c){var ctx=c.getContext("2d");var dpr=window.devicePixelRatio||1;var bsr=ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio||ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio||ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio||ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio||ctx.backingStorePixelRatio||1;var ratio=dpr/bsr;var oldWidth=c.width;var oldHeight=c.height;c.width=oldWidth*ratio;c.height=oldHeight*ratio;c.style.width=oldWidth+'px';c.style.height=oldHeight+'px';ctx.scale(ratio,ratio)};var rToD=function rToD(rad){return rad/Math.PI*180};var dToR=function dToR(deg){return deg/180*Math.PI};var pToR=function pToR(percent){return dToR(percent/100*360)};var rToP=function rToP(rad){return rToD(rad)/360*100};var rAF=function(c){return window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.oRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame||function(callback){window.setTimeout(c,1000/60)}}();return this.each(function(idx,element){var el=$(element);var cache={};var _data=el.data();for(var key in _data){if(_data.hasOwnProperty(key)&&key.indexOf('_cache_')===0){if(defaults.hasOwnProperty(key.substring(7))){cache[key.substring(7)]=_data[key]}}}
var settings=Object.assign({},defaults,cache,_data,options);for(var _key in settings){if(_key.indexOf('_cache_')!==0)el.data('_cache_'+_key,settings[_key])}
if(!$("canvas.circleChart_canvas",el).length){el.append(function(){return $('<canvas/>',{'class':'circleChart_canvas'}).prop({width:settings.size,height:settings.size}).css(settings.autoCss?{"margin-left":"auto","margin-right":"auto","display":"block"}:{})});scaleCanvas($("canvas",el).get(0))}
if(!$("p.circleChart_text",el).length){if(settings.text!==!1){el.append("<p class='circleChart_text'>"+settings.text+"</p>");if(settings.autoCss){if(settings.textCenter){$("p.circleChart_text",el).css({"position":"absolute","line-height":settings.size+"px","top":0,"width":"100%","margin":0,"padding":0,"text-align":"center","font-size":settings.textSize!==!1?settings.textSize:settings.size*settings.relativeTextSize,"font-weight":settings.textWeight,"font-family":settings.textFamily})}else{$("p.circleChart_text",el).css({"padding-top":"5px","text-align":"center","font-weight":settings.textWeight,"font-family":settings.textFamily,"font-size":settings.textSize!==!1?settings.textSize:settings.size*settings.relativeTextSize})}}}}
if(settings.autoCss){el.css("position","relative")}
if(!settings.redraw){settings.cAngle=settings.currentCAngle?settings.currentCAngle:settings.cAngle;settings.startAngle=settings.currentStartAngle?settings.currentStartAngle:settings.startAngle}
var c=$("canvas",el).get(0);var ctx=c.getContext("2d");var units={'percent':pToR,'rad':function rad(e){return e},'default':dToR};var f=units[settings.unit]||units['default'];var bAngle=f(settings.startAngle);var eAngle=f(settings.value);var cAngle=f(settings.cAngle);var pos=settings.size/2;var radius=pos*(1-settings.widthRatio/2);var lineWidth=radius*settings.widthRatio;var circle=Circle(pos,bAngle,eAngle,cAngle,radius,lineWidth,cAngle,settings);el.data("size",settings.size);if(!settings.animate){circle.cAngle=circle.eAngle;rAF(function(){ctx.clearRect(0,0,settings.size,settings.size);if(settings.background){circle.drawBackground(ctx)}
if(settings.value!==0){circle.draw(ctx);circle.setCurrentAnglesData(el)}else{if(circle.settings.background){circle.drawBackground(ctx)}}
circle.onDraw(el)})}else{if(settings.value!==0){circle.animate(el,ctx,new Date().getTime(),new Date().getTime(),cAngle>eAngle)}else{rAF(function(){ctx.clearRect(0,0,settings.size,settings.size);if(circle.settings.background){circle.drawBackground(ctx)}
circle.onDraw(el)})}}})}})(jQuery)</script>

<div class="circleChart" id="0"></div>
```